# rock paper scissors buttons don't do anything when clicked

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create a rock paper scissors game that allows a user to click either 'rock' 'paper' or 'scissors' buttons to play. When the user clicks the buttons it should tell the user what they chose, what the computer chose, and what the game results are.

Instead of this happening, I just have buttons that do not do anything when clicked. It tells me that they are undefined but I defined them so I'm not sure what to do.

```
from tkinter import *
from random import randint 

def main():
  computer = randint(1,3)
  results = show_message(player_number, computer)
  print(results)


def comp():
  computer = randint(1,3)
  return computer

def show_message(player_number, computer):
  if player_number == 1 and computer == 1:
    str_var.set("player chose rock, computer chose rock: tie")
  elif player_number == 2 and computer == 2:
    str_var.set("player chose paper, computer chose rock: tie")
  elif player_number == 3 and computer == 3:
      str_var.set("player chose scissors, computer chose scissors: tie")
  elif player_number == 1 and computer == 2:
      str_var.set("player chose rock, computer chose paper: computer wins")
  elif player_number == 1 and computer == 3:
      str_var.set("player chose rock, computer chose scissors: player wins")
  elif player_number == 2 and computer == 1:
      str_var.set("player chose paper, computer chose rock: player wins")
  elif player_number == 2 and computer == 3:
      str_var.set("player chose paper, computer chose scissors: computer wins")
  elif player_number == 3 and computer == 1:
      str_var.set("player chose scissors, computer chose rock: computer wins")
  else: 
      str_var.set("player chose scissors, computer chose paper: player wins")

#functions to set message
def rock_clicked(event=None):
  player_number = 1
  computer = randint(1,3)
  show_message(player_number, computer)

def paper_clicked(event=None):
  player_number = 2
  computer = randint(1,3)
  show_message(player_number, computer)

def scissors_clicked(event=None):
  player_number = 3
  computer = randint(1,3)
  show_message(player_number, computer)

root = Tk()
root.title("MY FIRST GAME")
root.geometry("300x150")


#variables
str_var = StringVar()
str_var.set("")
player_number = IntVar()

#make top frame
top_frame = Frame(root)
top_frame.pack(side=TOP)
top_label = Label(top_frame, text="ROCK PAPER SCISSORS", bg="blue")
top_label.pack()

#make bottom frame
bottom_frame = Frame(root)
bottom_frame.pack(side=BOTTOM)

button_rock = Button(top_frame, text="rock")
button_rock.bind("<Button-1>", rock_clicked)
button_paper = Button(top_frame, text="paper")
button_paper.bind("<Button-1>", paper_clicked)
button_scissors = Button(top_frame, text="scissors")
button_scissors.bind("<Button-1>", scissors_clicked)

button_rock.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=30)
button_paper.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=30)
button_scissors.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=30)

Label(top_frame, textvariable=str_var).pack(side=BOTTOM, padx=10, pady=40)


main()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: you aren't displaying what is in `str_var` anywhere. Also, `computer` is being set to a boolean but you're comparing it to an integer. You should do some basic debugging such as printing out `player_number` and `computer` to see if they are what you think they are.

Comment: @BryanOakley where should I display it? I thought I was defining it in `show_message`

Comment: You are the only person who can answer where you should display it. Display it wherever you want.

Comment: You need to add this line: `Label(top_frame, textvariable=str_var).pack()` That provides a place for the value of str_var to be displayed.

Comment: its working now but only for the scissors button. any idea why?

Comment: @savannah because you wrote "play_number" instead of "player_number". Look at the terminal: you'd see that in the error message.

Comment: @savannah Also, all the `computer = randint in range (1,3)` calls are wrong. You need to use `computer = randint(1,3)`

Comment: BTW: button has `Button( ..., command=function)` so you don't need `bind("<Button-1>")`

Comment: @Novel I edited it to show what my code looks like now. I am still only getting the scissors button to work

Comment: @savannah your code works for me. Make the window bigger to see it work. It works a lot better if you move the Label I gave you right before you define the bottom_frame, and leave out the pack arguments.